# Permisions in REST API using Spring Boot and LDAP

Tags: java, spring-boot, permissions, ldap, spring-ldap

I have configured LDAP (at this moment via `ldif` file) and successfully integrated with spring boot (spring boot exposes REST API).  I mean that only authorized requests (by `Basic Auth`) are serviced, other requests are rejected (`401` code).

My REST API exposes two urls:

```
(1) /deleteUser/id

(2) /showUser/id
```

And two groups of user in LDAP `A`, and `B`.

I would like to configure spring-boot security in such way that users from group `A` can consume both `(1)` and `(2)`, but users from group `B` can consume only `(2)`.

How to configure it ?

Comment: use `spring-security`. See https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ for further information on how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the @PreAuthorize,@PostAuthorize annotations provided by spring. They allow you to define method level access control.